# Run windows application in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have developed a windows application which extracts the required data from a web site and stores data in crm. Now i have added a button on ribbon , from which i want to call the windows application. I'm able to do this using below code

```
function resume()
{

var _Object=new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" ) ;
_Object.Run("C:\\ResumeGrab\\ResumeGrab.exe" );
}
```

The problem now i'm facing is, the button is working only in local system. I want to run this application from any system using the crm. I tried copying the .exe file in server and tried to run it , but when i tried its only running in server but not in any system. How to make this application run in multiple system without needing the .exe file copied in local system on click of button on ribbon in crm 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your client machines will need the `.exe`. I worked on a project where the employees of the company had to be able to run an application when a button on the ribbon was clicked and this is how we went about it.

So just an extra deployment step! Copy `.exe` to `c:\ResumeGrab` on client machines.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you redevelop it as a web service and invoke the servie from the button click?

Comment: No . I can't develop this as web service. This has to be windows app only.

Comment: Why? From the limited info you state, a windows app doesn't sound like the tool for the job :-S

Answer (score 0):

I have used "[web deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)" a couple of times in situations like this.

Comment: I want windows application to be run on button click not web application.

Comment: Check the link, it is a windows app.

Answer (score 0):

As long as everyone has access to it, I'd think putting it on a network share would be a little easier than trying to deploy it to every client machine.